# Make candies in a smallest number of days

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, optimization

I have been trying to digest the code in the editorial component of the problem [Making Candies](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/making-candies/problem) on Hackerrank. However, disappointingly, I can only understand the algorithm description while getting confused on the code.

```cpp
    #include<bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;
    typedef long long ll;

    bool check(ll machines, ll workers, ll price, ll target, ll rounds) {
        if (machines >= (target+workers-1)/workers) return true;
        ll cur = machines*workers;
        rounds--;
        if (rounds == 0) return false;
        while (1) {
            ll rem = target - cur;
            ll rnds = (rem + machines*workers - 1) / (machines*workers);
            if (rnds <= rounds) return true;
            if (cur < price) {
              rem = price - cur;
              rnds = (rem + machines*workers - 1) / (machines*workers);
              rounds -= rnds;
              if (rounds < 1) return false;
              cur += rnds * machines * workers;
            }
            cur -= price;
            if (machines > workers) {
              workers++;
            } else {
              machines++;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    int main(){
        ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
        cin.tie(0);
        ll m, w, p, n;
        cin >> m >> w >> p >> n;
        ll a = 1, b = 1000000000000LL;
        while (a < b) {
            ll mid = (a + b) >> 1;
            if (check(m, w, p, n, mid)) {
              b = mid;
            } else {
              a = mid + 1;
            }
        }
        cout << a << "\n";
        return 0;
    }
```

In particular, I don't understand this specific line:

```cpp
    rnds = (rem + machines*workers - 1) / (machines*workers);
```

Why is there `-1`? I would be grateful if someone could help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explaining the "specific" line

```
rnds = (rem + machines*workers - 1) / (machines*workers);
```

Here you simply calculate how more rounds are needed before a work unit (worker or machine) can be purchased.

Presumably, your main confusion is with `machines*workers - 1`. This adjustment is needed to not lose one round. Imagine, a case as follows:

```
rem = 13 // how more candies have to produced
machines = 1 
workers = 5
```

In the example above, you need `3` more days to accomplish the goal since at the end of round `2` you will only have `10` candies, and that's less than `13`.

However, if you include the adjustment expression `machines*workers - 1`:

```
(rem + machines*workers - 1) / (machines*workers)
```

Then, you will get the correct result `(13+5*1-1)/5 = 17/5 = 3`

### Explaining the problem

To accumulate a given number of candies, at each round we can do one of three actions:

1. Calculate how many more rounds are needed to accumulate the candies with the same set of machines and workers.
2. Purchase some machines/workers if we have enough money.
3. Purchase nothing and proceed to the next round,

Choice 1) or 3) is pretty straightforward, but what about 2) ? It's not clear how many machines/workers should be purchased if we have money for more than 1 unit.

The answer is - purchase as many work "units" as you can.  Also, purchase such units that maximise the product `m*w` by incrementing the smaller number of "units", and if it reaches the larger number, then keep both numbers as close as possible (the larger number must never become smaller).

For example, `m = 4`, `w = 2` and you can buy `5` more units. Then, first equalise the smaller number `w = 2 + 2 = 4`. Then, divide remaining `3` in favour of `m = 4 + 2 = 6` and `w = 4 + 1 = 5`.

Now, our approach should consist of the following steps:

1. Add candies for the current round to the total number of candies.
2. Calculate how many more rounds are left if no more tools are purchased. If the total number of rounds is less than the current minimum, the update the minimum. Otherwise, stop the procedure.
3. If the total number of candies is not enough to "invest", play as many rounds as needed to collect enough.
4. Buy as many "units" as possible and adjust their number accordingly

### Code

```
uint64_t minimumPasses(uint64_t m, uint64_t w, uint64_t p, uint64_t n) {    
    if ((n / m) <= w) {
        return 1;
    }
    
    uint64_t currentProductionStorage = 0;
    uint64_t minRounds = std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>().max();
    uint64_t currentRounds = 0;
    uint64_t currentProductionSpeed;
    
    while (true) {      
        currentRounds++; 
        currentProductionSpeed = m * w;
        currentProductionStorage += currentProductionSpeed;
        uint64_t roundsWithoutFurtherInvest = 0;
        if (n >= currentProductionStorage) {
            roundsWithoutFurtherInvest = (n + currentProductionSpeed - 1 - currentProductionStorage) / (currentProductionSpeed);    
        }
        
        if (minRounds < currentRounds + roundsWithoutFurtherInvest) {
            break;    
        }
        minRounds = currentRounds + roundsWithoutFurtherInvest;
        
        if (currentProductionStorage < p) {
            uint64_t roundsBeforeInvest = (p + currentProductionSpeed - 1 - currentProductionStorage) / currentProductionSpeed;
            currentProductionStorage += (roundsBeforeInvest * m * w);
            currentRounds += roundsBeforeInvest;
        }
        
        uint64_t numOfPurchasedUnits = currentProductionStorage / p;
        currentProductionStorage %= p;
        
        uint64_t diff = std::llabs(w - m);
        uint64_t part1 = numOfPurchasedUnits; 
        uint64_t part2 = 0;
        if (diff < numOfPurchasedUnits) {
            uint64_t remainingPurchasedUnits = numOfPurchasedUnits - diff; 
            part1 = diff + (remainingPurchasedUnits / 2);
            part2 = (remainingPurchasedUnits / 2) + (remainingPurchasedUnits % 2);
        }
        
        if (m > w) {
            w += part1;
            m += part2;
        } else {
            m += part1;
            w += part2;
        }
    }
    
    return minRounds;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

With a (not so) little help from [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28r%20%2B%20m%20%2A%20w%20-%201%29%20%2F%20%28m%20%2A%20w%29), the expression

```
ll rnds = (rem + machines*workers - 1) / (machines*workers);
```

translates to

```
ll rnds = (rem - 1) / (machines * workers) + 1;
```

i.e., given `rem - 1`, how many rounds are expected for `(machine * workers)`, the current workforce?

Answer (score -1):

Here's the complete code I submitted in Python. Thanks, @shrike-danny

```
import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

def check_more_or_less_rounds(machines, workers, price, target, rounds):
    if machines * workers >= target:
        # We have more work power than needed, so keep looking left wise
        return -1

    rounds -= 1
    
    if rounds == 0:
        # Have we found the pivot?
        return 1
    
    curr = machines * workers
    
    while True:
        # Given the current workload, compute the remaining rounds
        remaining        = target - curr
        remaining_rounds = (remaining - 1) // (machines * workers) + 1
        
        # We have more rounds than needed, so keep looking left wise
        if remaining_rounds <= rounds: return -1
        
        # if this production round yield less than the 'price'
        if curr < price:
            # compute how many rounds to produce enough to match 'price'
            remaining        = price - curr
            remaining_rounds = (remaining - 1) // (machines * workers) + 1
            
            rounds -= remaining_rounds
            
            # We don't have enough rounds to par the price, so keep looking to the right
            if rounds < 1: return 1
            
            curr += remaining_rounds * machines * workers
            
        # Do the hire or purchase
        if machines > workers:
            workers += 1
        else:
            machines += 1
            
        # Do debit the price
        curr -= price

# Complete the minimumPasses function below.
def minimumPasses(m, w, p, n):
    min_rounds = 1
    max_rounds = n;

    while min_rounds < max_rounds:
        mid = (min_rounds + max_rounds) // 2;
        
        if check_more_or_less_rounds(m, w, p, n, mid) < 0:
            max_rounds = mid
        else:
            min_rounds = mid + 1
            
    return min_rounds

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    mwpn = input().split()

    m = int(mwpn[0])

    w = int(mwpn[1])

    p = int(mwpn[2])

    n = int(mwpn[3])

    result = minimumPasses(m, w, p, n)

    fptr.write(str(result) + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```